# Integer promotions в c

Tags: c

Вопрос короткий.

```
unsigned char c = 1, d = 2;
printf("%d %d %d",sizeof(c),sizeof(d),sizeof(c&d)); // выводит 1 1 4
```

Скажите, почему при конъюнкции получившееся выражение становится типа int? В стандарте C99 четко сказано, что:

> The integer promotions are applied only: as part of the usual arithmetic conversions, to certain
>   argument expressions, to the operands of the unary +, -, and ~ operators, and to both operands of the
>   shift operators, as specified by their respective subclauses.

В чем причина? Буду благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так это и есть действие *the usual arithmetic conversions*, о которых говорится в вашей цитате. Спецификация бинарного `&` ясно говорит

> **6.5.10 Bitwise AND operator**
>   **3** The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.

Для целочисленных типов the usual arithmetic conversions начинаются с integer promotions. В вашем случае сработали именно integer promotions и тип `unsigned char` был превращен в тип `int`.