# Почему результат работы битового оператора "дополнение" имеет такой вид?

Tags: c

```
int main() {
    short int n = 0x00a4;   /* 00000000 10100100 */

    printf("~n == %04x\n", ~n);

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
~n == ffffff5b
```

Но почему не `ff5b`, ведь применяя этот оператор на число `00000000 10100100` получим `11111111 01011011`, а дальше `1111` в двоичной системе равняется `f` в шестнадцатеричной и т.д. Откуда берутся ещё четыре числа `f`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это означает, что на вашей платформе тип `int` шире типа `short` и, очевидно, имеет ширину 32 бита.

В вашем случае оператор `~` не применяется "на число `00000000 10100100`", как вы неправильно предположили. В языке С нет "вычислительных" операторов, работающих на малых целочисленных типах. Минимальным целым типом для вычислений является тип `int` (или `unsigned int`) (cм. "integer promotions"). И ваше `n` перед применением оператора `~` будет приведено к типу `int`, и результат будет иметь тип `int`.

То есть на платформе с 32-битным `int` работаете вы фактически именно с числом `00000000 00000000 00000000 10100100` и в результате получаете `11111111 11111111 11111111 01011011`. Его вы и печатаете своим `printf`.

Если вы хотите получить результат типа `short int` - либо сами аккуратно приводите его к этому типу, либо просите `printf` печатать его как `short int` значение. А вообще битовыми экспериментами и манипуляциями лучше заниматься в рамках *беззнаковых* типов.

См. также

[Integer promotions в c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/898036/integer-promotions-%D0%B2-c)
[Определение типа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604456/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0/604466)

Comment: Подскажите, а если мы имеем два числа формата short int и применяем к ним оператор и, или, исключающее или, то на выходе получим просто int? Пример: `n & m`, где n и m - short int
Или здесь также работает "Минимальным целым типом для вычислений является тип int" ?

Comment: @Teddy: Да, и здесь работает то же правило. Результат имеет тип `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что если вы хотите именно `short int`, то нужно писать правильно -

```
%04hx
```

То, что написали вы - это преобразованное в `int` значение.